# Join ksql streams using computed expressions

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a table called `SUBSCRIPTIONS` with the following columns:

```
KEY varchar,
APPLICATION_ID varchar
SUBSCRIPTION_ID varchar
```

The KEY of this table is the `KEY` column which is composed of both APPLICATION_ID and SUBSCRIPTION_ID in the form as in `<APPLICATION_ID>_<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>`.

A stream called `NOTIFICATION_EVENTS_STREAM` contains the following columns:

```sql
APPLICATION_ID varchar
SUBSCRIPTION_ID varchar
NOTIFICATION_ID varchar
LOCATION_COUNTRY varchar
```

I need to join the NOTIFICATION_EVENTS_STREAM with the SUBSCRIPTIONS table to extract the `LOCATION_COUNTRY` column, I'm trying the following query but it doesn't seem to be working:

```sql
select e.application_id, e.notification_id, s.location_country, count(*) from NOTIFICATION_EVENTS_STREAM_RICH e LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTIONS s ON s.KEY = (e.APPLICATION_ID +'_'+ e.SUBSCRIPTION_ID) GROUP BY e.application_id, e.notification_id, s.location_country;
```

I get the following error:

```
 Line: 1, Col: 148 : Invalid join criteria (S.KEY = ((E.APPLICATION_ID + '_') + E.SUBSCRIPTION_ID)). Could not find a join criteria operand for E.
```

Temporarily I've created the following stream to get the composed column but it should not be necessary:

```
CREATE STREAM NOTIFICATION_EVENTS_STREAM_RICH WITH (PARTITIONS=1) AS SELECT APPLICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, KIND, APPLICATION_ID +'_'+NOTIFICATION_ID AS NOTIFICATION_KEY, APPLICATION_ID+'_'+SUBSCRIPTION_ID AS SUBSCRIPTION_KEY FROM NOTIFICATION_EVENTS_STREAM;
```

Is there a way to use computed expressions in table joins?

Answer (score 1):

KSQL doesn't currently support this. You could comment/upvote [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/596) if you want.

You need to manually create an intermediate stream, per example here: https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/creating-composite-key

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*